# Cursor position changed in textview

Tags: python, textview, cursor, signals, pygtk

In PyGTK, I want to get the current position of the cursor whenever the cursor is moved inside a textview in my app. So I need to create a callback function and connect to a signal. 
But I'm not sure from where to get that signal.

Comment: Please answer with respect to **Pygtk**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to monitor the cursor-position property of the buffer, look at the example here below for monitoring the cursor position.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class CursorSample(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self, application_id="org.app.CursorSample")

        self.buffer = Gtk.TextBuffer()
        self.buffer.connect("notify::cursor-position",
                            self.on_cursor_position_changed)

        self.tw = Gtk.TextView()
        self.tw.set_buffer(self.buffer)
        self.tw.props.wrap_mode = Gtk.WrapMode.CHAR

    def do_activate(self):
        main_window = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        main_window.add(self.tw)
        self.add_window(main_window)
        main_window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        main_window.show_all()

    def on_cursor_position_changed(self, buffer, data=None):
        print buffer.props.cursor_position

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cursorsample = CursorSample()
    cursorsample.run(None)
```

Comment: That's for GTK 3, not PyGTK like the OP asked, but the principle of connecting to `notify::cursor-position` is the same.

Comment: PyGTK is not maintained anymore and shouldn't be used to write new code.

Comment: How do i connect to `notify::cursor-position` in Pygtk ?

Comment: @gianmt can u plz explain how to connect the same signal in pygtk
is it the same `notify::cursor-position`

Comment: @SayanPaul yes GTK3 and GTK2 have the same syntax for connecting the signals and, with small differences, for anything else, refer to https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject#Porting_PyGTK_to_PyGObject if you want to see the differences. You should really not write new code using PyGTK.