# Is it possible to get cursor coordinates in textview gtk

Tags: python, gtk

I am working on an app with Gtk using Pythons `gi.repository`. I would like to know if there it is possible to get the coordinates of the cursor relative to the screen any time it is moved in the text view.

e.g. it returns x1, x2, y1, y2 of the cursor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cursor position changed in textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063941/cursor-position-changed-in-textview)

Comment: no it just returns the line index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just bind the `TextView` to `"event"`, and in the handler function, check if the event type is `Gdk.EventType.MOTION_NOTIFY`.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gdk, Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()

def on_event(widget, event):
    # Check if the event is a mouse movement
    if event.type == Gdk.EventType.MOTION_NOTIFY:
        print(event.x, event.y) # Print the mouse's position in the window

t = Gtk.TextView()
t.connect("event", on_event)
win.add(t)

win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I had found an answer. Thanks anyways. I'll take this one as correct